# Policy causing error: ignored invalid attempt to bind route to a non-function controller

Tags: sails.js

Using SailsJS 0.10.5 on my Mac (installed using npm -g) and I am trying to apply a policy to a controllers action and I am getting this error:

```
error: In user.isloggedin, ignored invalid attempt to bind route to a non-function controller: { identity: 'isAuthenticated',
globalId: 'isauthenticated',
_middlewareType: 'POLICY: isAuthenticated' } for path:  /isLoggedIn
```

I have a controller with an action, a route in config/route.js, a policy in config/policies.js

**Additional Details**

If I don't use isAuthenticated in the config/policies.js file I do not get this error.

I am using passport with passport-local

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**config/policies.js**

```
module.exports.policies = {

    '*': true,
    UserController: {
        'signup': true,
        'isLoggedIn': 'isAuthenticated'
    },
    AuthController: {
        '*': true
    }
};
```

**config/routes.js**

```
module.exports.routes = {

    'post /signup' : {
        controller: 'UserController',
        action: 'signup',
    },
    '/isLoggedIn' : {
        controller : 'UserController',
        action : 'isLoggedIn'
    }
};
```

**api/controller/UserController.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {
    signup: function(req, res) {
        User.create(req.params.all()).exec(function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                return res.negotiate(err);
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return res.negotiate(err);
                }
                return res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    },
    isLoggedIn: function(req, res) {
        User.findOne({id: req.session.passport.user}).exec(function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                return;
            }
            res.json(user);
        });
    }
};
```

**api/policies/isAuthenticated.js**

```
module.export = function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('403!!!');
        return res.send(403, {message: 'Not Authorized' });
    }
    console.log('asdf');
    return next();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `module.export` to `module.exports` <- with an ***s*** in your file isAuthenticated.js

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed this one ha. Thanks for you help! :)